# How to clear text_input

Tags: streamlit

I got code from following repo: https://github.com/alejandro-ao/ask-multiple-pdfs

The purpose of code is to chat with documents, I have modified some aspects of it to soothe my needs better such as load all files from one folder etc...

The issue I am having is my lack of experience in streamlit.

What I am trying to do is following:

After question has been asked clear st.text_input.

Here is the code:

```
def handle_userinput(user_question):
    if not st.session_state.conversation:
        st.warning("Index not ready. Please wait a moment and try again.")
        return
    preface = "You are a helpful assistant: "
    bot_question = preface + user_question

    response = st.session_state.conversation({'question': bot_question})
    st.session_state.chat_history = response['chat_history']

    for i, message in enumerate(st.session_state.chat_history):
        if i % 2 == 0:  # User's message
            # Display only the original user's question without preface
            st.write(user_template.replace("{{MSG}}", user_question), unsafe_allow_html=True)
        else:  # Bot's response
            st.write(bot_template.replace("{{MSG}}", message.content), unsafe_allow_html=True)

def main():
    user_question = st.text_input("Ask a question:")
    if user_question:
        handle_userinput(user_question)
```

I have tried various methods from streamlit forum such as setting session_state and more but none of them helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this with a submit form the fields should clear when you press the button.

```py
with st.form("Question",clear_on_submit=True):
    user_question = st.text_input("Ask a question:")
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
    if submitted:
        handle_userinput(user_question)
```

an alternative method is to call
`submitted.empty()` after the content has been processed